# jQuery add list with images instead of text characters when typing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `input` and when I'm typing, let's say: **a**, I want the result to be `<li class="a"><img src="a.png" />` if is **space** => `<li class="space"></li>`.
This list appends to `ul.text`.

Also when I press **backspace** I need the last item to be removed.

I have this untill now, but I can't make it work:

```
$('input').live('keyup', function(e){
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
    var pressedLetter = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('ul.text').append('<li><img src="letters/'+pressedLetter+'.png" alt="" /></li>');
});
```

Any help, please?
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're appending a new element on each keyup to your `ul` element. You have to change the attributes of your `li`and `img` elements instead.

```
$('input').live('keyup', function (e) {
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
    var pressedLetter = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    if( $('ul.text').find('li').length < 1 && this.value.length > 0 ) {
        $('ul.text').append('<li><img/></li>'); //Append new elements (li,img) if they doesn't exist
    }else{    
        if (this.value.length < 1)  $('ul.text').find('li').remove(); //Remove element if value.length < 1
    }

    $('ul.text').find('li').attr('class', this.value);
    $('ul.text').find('img').attr('src', 'letters/' + pressedLetter + '.png');
});
```

<kbd>[JSfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/3ZQ4S/)</kbd>

Comment: in your demo it's working only with 1 character.. I need more 7-8 chars